# PeopleSoft Query Manager - string expression, trying to get the third set of ||

Tags: peoplesoft

In PeopleSoft I am trying to get some text from the middle of a cell. I'm having trouble with creating a string expression to do this. The data in the cell looks like this (I've **bolded** what I'm trying to capture):

> || SVP: Person Number one
>
> || Interview Completed by:  Person Number two
>
> || Info:  **Employee lists off a bunch of stuff.**
>
> || Non-Relevant Question? Y
>
> || Manager provided data to:  Person Number three

I've submitted a question [here](https://it.toolbox.com/question/pulling-out-data-after-piping-string-082119) and I've come close. Here's what I have so far:

```
substring(J.HR_NP_NOTE_TEXT,CHARINDEX('|| Info:',J.HR_NP_NOTE_TEXT)+8,100),CHARINDEX('||',J.HR_NP_NOTE_TEXT)
```

The problem is that this is not stopping at the ||. A better solution - if I knew how - would be if I could get the text that is after the third set of '||' and stop before the fourth set of '||'.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing your actual output, I think that you will find that your issue is to do with the way substring actually works.

From the Transact SQL documentation I can see online (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/substring-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) 
substring takes 3 arguments: 
SUBSTRING ( expression ,start , length )

you have the expression - J.HR_NP_NOTE_TEXT 
you have the start - CHARINDEX('|| Info:',J.HR_NP_NOTE_TEXT)+8,100) - I'm not 100% sure why you are only looking for the '|| Info:' after 100 characters though?

But then when you calculate the length - CHARINDEX('||',J.HR_NP_NOTE_TEXT) you are not going to get what you expect. Assuming that it ignores the earlier ||'s in the string (will it?), it will return a position in the string, not an actual length.

A more appropriate calculation would be something like 
(CHARINDEX('||',J.HR_NP_NOTE_TEXT)-CHARINDEX('|| Info:',J.HR_NP_NOTE_TEXT)+8,100)) 
i.e. the difference between detecting the '|| Info:' position and the next '||'.

Making your whole query: 
substring(J.HR_NP_NOTE_TEXT,CHARINDEX('|| Info:',J.HR_NP_NOTE_TEXT)+8,100),(CHARINDEX('||',J.HR_NP_NOTE_TEXT)-CHARINDEX('|| Info:',J.HR_NP_NOTE_TEXT)+8,100)).

As I'm not entirely sure about your CHARINDEX looking for '||', I would probably try this one though - to find the next '||' after '|| Info:'
substring(J.HR_NP_NOTE_TEXT,CHARINDEX('|| Info:',J.HR_NP_NOTE_TEXT)+8,100),(CHARINDEX('||',J.HR_NP_NOTE_TEXT,CHARINDEX('|| Info:',J.HR_NP_NOTE_TEXT)+8,100))-CHARINDEX('|| Info:',J.HR_NP_NOTE_TEXT)+8,100)).

Although this is a question you're asking about a PS Query, you may get better answers from people who are focused primarily on the SQL language you're using too, as this is not strictly speaking a PeopleSoft only question.

Hope that helps!